# Is there a system for determining the class of a rocket?

Tags: launch-vehicle

I'm not so sure on the specs. So, I'll just look up my handy spacey rocket class chart, oh, I don't have one. The system should class rockets into these classes: light, medium, and heavy. The real question here is does a rocket class rating system even exist, if so, how does it work?

Comment: What's a 'rocket class rating system' supposed to be? Rockets have mass and filling according to their target-$\Delta v$'s, suborbital, LEO, GEO, interplanetary ...

Comment: Oh wait, if you did a bit of research you would have found one. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_vehicle#Mass_to_orbit

Comment: @Topcode why thank you. that is actually helpful. But I usually tend to stay away from Wikipedia.

Comment: @percythemarsrover if the original source is better, here it is https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/500393main_TA01-LaunchPropulsion-DRAFT-Nov2010-A.pdf

Comment: @Topcode ah, there's lot of detail. thanks.

Comment: speaking of space classes: [How do NASA Venture Class Launch Services Contracts work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32931/12102) (currently unanswered) and [Are there now established classes of solar-electric powered spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50043/12102) and [How might one redesign a "Curiosity-class" rover for a mission to Vesta or Ceres?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48928/12102)

Comment: The Nasa paper from 2010 mentions a "Corona proof" system for 2021 in figure 1. They knew what would happen! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> The system should class rockets into these classes: light, medium, and heavy.

Most organizations use the following:

- Light rockets can only put less than 2000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit.
- Medium rockets can put 2000 kg to 20000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit.
- Heavy rockets can put over 20000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit.

Some split heavy rockets into two classes, heavy and super heavy. Heavy lift vehicles can put over 20000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit, but no more than 50000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit. Super heavy lift vehicles can put over 50000 kg of payload into low Earth orbit.